# How much value has the US Dollar lost or gained in 2020, compared to the US Dollar in 2019?

Tags: currency, economics, government, central-bank

There's a lot of news about the Federal Reserve printing money. I have a hard time imagining the relative change in value of the USD. (or EURO for that matter)

I tried to calculate but it's hard:

- The money that is easily perceived as money Money Zero Maturity (MZM: M1, M2 and more) was 16 trillion in 2019 (Ref.: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/moneyzeromaturity.asp )
- Federal Reserve had raised their balance sheet from 300 billion to +6 trillion since the start of the year. (Ref. 1: https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-fed-balancesheet/fed-balance-sheet-increases-to-record-6-42-trillion-idUSKBN21Y3JD , Ref 2: https://www.livemint.com/news/world/fed-bets-on-binge-buying-bonds-to-spur-us-economy-11586712851307.html )

The Federal Reserve is buying back federal bonds from banks, they're lending money to states and they just started buying Futures too. I can't easily see where the money is flowing to.

Any ideas? A rough decile/percentile estimate will do.

Comment: Considering that there's a gargantuan amount of foreign debt denominated in USD, it may be outright impossible to come up with even a rough estimate for the value of USD today.

Comment: Also worth noting relative comparisons here tricky as all the other major currency pairs are also printing en masse, so its not just the Fed's actions that matter.